# Fine Grained SSRS Security Setup

Tags: security, reporting-services, reporting

I want to control who can view my SSRS reports based on  following things?

Company of the Person

Designation of the Person

Department of the Person

Rank of the Person

How do I achieve that? Can somebody provide me step by step instructions or point me to right direction.

Thank You,

kalpesh

Answer (score 0):

Search Active Directory in search portals. Then, I am sure you'll have some information how to handle these things.